# Python & Matlab Difference in Matrix Calculation for Nesting Loop

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

x=[ 2061075.875,  2061801,  2061154.25,  2061605.75,  2061314.375]
y=[ 10638640,  10639060,  10638727,  10639118,  10638802]
st=[ 73.92976,  71.13528,  64.40809,  71.80971,  72.72918]
l=[ 254.96384,  239.15473,  200.20001,  218.91659,  185.49989]

deltaL=10

N=np.floor(np.divide(l,deltaL))

for i in range(0,len(x)):

    if (int(N[i]/2)==N[i]/2):

        px_down = np.zeros((len(x),max(np.floor(N/2))))
        py_down = np.zeros((len(x),max(np.floor(N/2))))

        for j in range(0,int(N[i]/2)):

                px_down[i,j]=x[i]-(deltaL*j)*np.sin(st[i]*np.pi/180)
                py_down[i,j]=y[i]-(deltaL*j)*np.cos(st[i]*np.pi/180)

    else:

        px_down = np.zeros((len(x),max(np.floor(N/2))))
        py_down = np.zeros((len(x),max(np.floor(N/2))))

        for j in range(0,int((N[i]-1)/2)):

                px_down[i,j]=x[i]-(deltaL*j)*np.sin(st[i]*np.pi/180)
                py_down[i,j]=y[i]-(deltaL*j)*np.cos(st[i]*np.pi/180)
```

The result of px_down and y_down is strange and many zeros in these two matrix. But using MATLAB, we obtain that:

```
2061066.26576935  2061056.65653871    2061047.04730806    2061037.43807742    2061027.82884677    2061018.21961613    2061008.61038548    2060999.00115484    2060989.39192419    2060979.78269355    2060970.17346290    2060960.56423225
2061791.53715368  2061782.07430735    2061772.61146103    2061763.14861471    2061753.68576838    2061744.22292206    2061734.76007574    2061725.29722942    2061715.83438309    2061706.37153677    2061696.90869045    0
2061145.23106473  2061136.21212947    2061127.19319420    2061118.17425893    2061109.15532367    2061100.13638840    2061091.11745313    2061082.09851787    2061073.07958260    2061064.06064733    0   0
2061596.24975030  2061586.74950061    2061577.24925091    2061567.74900121    2061558.24875151    2061548.74850182    2061539.24825212    2061529.74800242    2061520.24775272    2061510.74750303    0   0
2061304.82587875  2061295.27675750    2061285.72763625    2061276.17851501    2061266.62939376    2061257.08027251    2061247.53115126    2061237.98203001    2061228.43290876    0   0   0
```

Does anyone has an idea of solving this problem? Thanks very much for your help!!!

Comment: What's the Matlab code? Try creating a small example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it may help you find the problem yourself, or at least pinpoint it to a specific part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your matricies. Try this:

```
import numpy as np

x=[ 2061075.875,  2061801,  2061154.25,  2061605.75,  2061314.375]
y=[ 10638640,  10639060,  10638727,  10639118,  10638802]
st=[ 73.92976,  71.13528,  64.40809,  71.80971,  72.72918]
l=[ 254.96384,  239.15473,  200.20001,  218.91659,  185.49989]

deltaL=10

N=np.floor(np.divide(l,deltaL))

px_down = np.zeros((len(x),max(np.floor(N/2))))
py_down = np.zeros((len(x),max(np.floor(N/2))))

for i in range(0,len(x)):

    if (int(N[i]/2)==N[i]/2):



        for j in range(0,int(N[i]/2)):

                px_down[i,j]=x[i]-(deltaL*j)*np.sin(st[i]*np.pi/180)
                py_down[i,j]=y[i]-(deltaL*j)*np.cos(st[i]*np.pi/180)

    else:



        for j in range(0,int((N[i]-1)/2)):

                px_down[i,j]=x[i]-(deltaL*j)*np.sin(st[i]*np.pi/180)
                py_down[i,j]=y[i]-(deltaL*j)*np.cos(st[i]*np.pi/180)
```